# move item from one treeview to another treeview same line of row

Tags: python, python-3.x, treeview

**Is there any possibility to send the data from one table to another .I want to move data from tv to tv3 same line of row you can see in screenshot https://prnt.sc/1dcjfhq**

```
# Frame for TreeView
frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP,pady=25)

tv2 = ttk.Treeview(frame2, columns=(1), show="headings", height="15")
tv2.pack()
tv2.heading(1, text="All word")

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP,pady=25)

tv = ttk.Treeview(frame1, columns=(1), show="headings", height="15")
tv.pack()
tv.heading(1, text="one word")

frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.pack(side=tk.TOP,pady=25)

tv3 = ttk.Treeview(frame3, columns=(1), show="headings", height="15")
tv3.pack()
tv3.heading(1, text="Valid Word")

frame1.grid(row=0,column=1)
frame2.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5)
frame3.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=5)
tv.bind("<Double-1>", addToValid)
    def addToValid(self):
        item = tv.item(tv.selection())['values'][0]
        print("you clicked on move", item)


        for ic in range(1):
            print('ic',ic)
            tv3.move(item,tv.parent(ic), tv3.index(ic))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for ic in range(1):
    print('ic',ic)
    tv3.move(item,tv.parent(ic), tv3.index(ic))
```

Try:

```
tv3.move(item,tv.parent(0), tv3.index(0))
```

Comment: this is not suitable  "ic" is not define as per your suggestion

Comment: Sorry @U11-Forward it doesnot work did you see the screenshot it will make more clear